# Error: Could not find 'blazor_apexchart.renderChart' ('blazor_apexchart' was undefined)

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, apexcharts, blazor-jsinterop

I have used blazor wrapper for apexchart.js to build a chart Component. this is my ApexChart razor component.

```
<BLChartContainer>

                @if (chartDetails!=null)
                {
                    <ApexChart @ref=_detailsChart TItem="LocationViseStockResponse"
                                    Title="Stocks"
                                    OnDataPointSelection=DataPointsSelected
                                    Debug>

                                <ApexPointSeries TItem="LocationViseStockResponse"
                                     Items="chartDetails"
                                     Name=""
                                     SeriesType="SeriesType.Bar"
                                     XValue="@(e => e.Location.CodeName)"
                                     YValue="@(e => e.Qty)"
                                     OrderByDescending="e=>e.X" />

                    </ApexChart>
                }

</BLChartContainer>

@code{

    private ApexChart<LocationViseStockResponse> _detailsChart;
    private SelectedData<LocationViseStockResponse> selectedData;
    private IList<LocationViseStockResponse> chartDetails;

   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
     _detailsChart = new();
      chartDetails= new List<LocationViseStockResponse>();
      //..
   }

   private void DataPointsSelected(SelectedData<LocationViseStockResponse> selectedData)
    {
        this.selectedData = selectedData;
        _detailsChart?.SetRerenderChart();
    }

}
```

but when I run the application I am getting this console error.

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'blazor_apexchart.renderChart' ('blazor_apexchart' was undefined).
> Error: Could not find 'blazor_apexchart.renderChart' ('blazor_apexchart' was undefined).
> at https://localhost:5050/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:328
> at Array.forEach ()
> at a.findFunction (https://localhost:5050/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:296)
> at _ (https://localhost:5050/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:2437)
> at https://localhost:5050/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3325
> at new Promise ()
> at Object.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:5050/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3306)
> at Object.Rt [as invokeJSFromDotNet] (https://localhost:5050/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:59738)
> at _mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor (https://localhost:5050/_framework/dotnet.6.0.0.rbisnsgo77.js:1:193780)
> at wasm://wasm/00945abe:wasm-function[2588]:0x8065b

what is the exact issue??please help me ,appriciate all your helps

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because `Blazor-ApexCharts` only works if you put `@using ApexCharts;` in `_Imports.razor` and not directly in the component/page.

Comment: This is not true (at least for Blazor Server-side). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74204262/10534901). Leaving this comment for anyone in future to save them from the rabbit hole I went down because of a namespace conflict I had if I included it in `_Imports.razor`.

Comment: It is (was?) true for Blazor WASM, and regarding the tags OP is using Blazor WASM not server.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error with the project properly set up.

Closing and re-opening Visual Studio resolved the problem.

Note [this issue](https://github.com/apexcharts/Blazor-ApexCharts/issues/111) indicating there may be a problem with hot reloading when Apex Charts is first added to a project.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the required JS files in _Host.cshtml.

From the project [Github](https://github.com/apexcharts/Blazor-ApexCharts):

> In `_Host.cshtml` (server-side) or in `index.html` (client-side) add the following lines to the `body` tag after the `_framework` reference:
>
> ```html
> <script src="_content/Blazor-ApexCharts/js/apex-charts.min.js"></script>
> <script src="_content/Blazor-ApexCharts/js/blazor-apex-charts.js"></script>
> ```